# SQL query to retrieve distinct records from four tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four tables:

- Department (DepartmentId)
- Course (CourseId, DepartmentId)
- CourseInstructor (CourseId, InstructorId)
- Instructor (InstructorId, FirstName, LastName, HireDate)

I am working on asp.net mvc. The Instructor model is -

```
public class Instructor
{
  public int InstructorId {get; set;}
  public string FristName {get; set;}
  public string LastName {get; set;}
  public DateTime HireDate {get; set;}
  public string FullName 
  {
     get 
     {
       return FirstName + " " + LastName;
     } 
  }
```

Now I need to find all distinct Instructor record of a Department based on a given DepartmentId.

I wrote the following sql query, but it says -

> Ambiguous column name 'InstructorId'

```
string query = "select InstructorId, MAX(FirstName), MAX(LastName) from Instructor "
            + "left join CourseInstructor on CourseInstructor.InstructorId = Instructor.InstructorId "
            + "left join Course on Course.CourseId = CourseInstructor.CourseId "
            + "left join Department on Department.DepartmentId=Course.DepartmentId "
            + "where Department.DepartmentId=@p0 "
            + "group by Instructor.InstructorId";
        IEnumarable<Instructor> Instructors = db.Database.SqlQuery<Instructor>(query, id);
```

Here id is the given DepartmentId. How can I solve this.

Comment: Use qualified column names (i.e. always with a table alias) and you will *never* have this prbolem.

Comment: It would have been better to ask a new question, rather than  editing the old one.  The answers provided for the original question no longer make sense.  This will confuse those that follow you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of aggregation is suspect.  Here is an alternative that uses `exists`:

```
select i.*
from Instructor i
where exists (select 1
              from CourseInstructor ci join 
                   Course c
                   on c.CourseId = ci.CourseId 
              where ci.InstructorId = i.InstructorId and
                    c.DepartmentId = @p0
             );
```

Notes:

- This version does not require aggregation, so it should be faster.
- The `join` to `Department` is unnecessary because the id is in the `Course` table.
- The `left join`s are unnecessary because your query requires a match on `DepartmentId`.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Fully qualified column names prevent the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Because the InstructorId appears in more than one table SQL Server does not know which to return.  There are two ways to address this.

You can append the table name in front of the column name.  So `SELECT InstructorId...` becomes `SELECT Instructor.InstructorId...`.

Or you can reduce the amount of typing by [aliasing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx) your tables, and appending the alias before the column name.

```
select 
    i.InstructorId, 
    MAX(i.FirstName), 
    MAX(i.LastName) 
from 
    Instructor AS i
         left outer join CourseInstructor AS ci         on ci.InstructorId  = i.InstructorId 
         left outer join Course on AS c                 on c.CourseId       = ci.CourseId 
         left outer join Department AS d                on d.DepartmentId   = c.DepartmentId 
where 
    d.DepartmentId=@p0 
group by 
    i.InstructorId
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify all column names which are present in two or more selected tables:

```
 string query = "select Instructor.InstructorId, MAX(Instructor.FirstName), MAX(Instructor.LastName) from Instructor "
                + "left join CourseInstructor on CourseInstructor.InstructorId = Instructor.InstructorId "
                + "left join Course on Course.CourseId = CourseInstructor.CourseId "
                + "left join Department on Department.DepartmentId=Course.DepartmentId "
                + "where Department.DepartmentId=@p0 "
                + "group by Instructor.InstructorId";
            IEnumarable<Instructor> Instructors = db.Database.SqlQuery<Instructor>(query, id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query

```
string query = "select Instructor.InstructorId, MAX(FirstName), MAX(LastName) from Instructor "
        + "left join CourseInstructor on CourseInstructor.InstructorId = Instructor.InstructorId "
        + "left join Course on Course.CourseId = CourseInstructor.CourseId "
        + "left join Department on Department.DepartmentId=Course.DepartmentId "
        + "where Department.DepartmentId=@p0 "
        + "group by Instructor.InstructorId";
```